# How to traverse territories in Salesforce using SOQL

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a field on contact object called 'Region' (Text formual field) whose end value would be in the range of 1-5. On the other hand, I have a territory model setup in my Salesforce instance. There are 5 territories with the Type Region that come on level 3 in model hierarchy.
Here is my territory hierarchy
[Territory hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX3Rb.png)

Here are the five region type territories
[Region Type territories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggMHe.png)

What I want is that if the value in Region field is 1 on contact page, it should go to the  Region 1 territory and check the assigned users in the region 1. Similarly for other regions. I am taking an example where Region value on contact object is 3. In that case, I want the code to go to Region 3,  Traverse the assigned users in region 3 and check the "Role in Territory field" in assigned user. And then there is some other processing. Right now I don't even know how to reach to that point.

Screenshot attached for Region 3.
[Region 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjrk.png)

Comment: You may get more answers to this if you try posting to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @berry120 Thanks Berry. I have posted there too. Hoping to get a quick response.